# Angular: forkJoin deprecated?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Today, I opened my Angular project and I found a warning saying:

```
forkJoin is deprecated: resultSelector is deprecated, pipe to map instead (deprecation)
```

[image]

I googled it, but I found very little and I don't know how to get rid of the warning. How do I have to use `map` instead of `forkJoin`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`forkJoin` isn't deprecated. Only its variant with a result selector function is deprecated.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/forkJoin.ts#L29

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#howto-result-selector-migration

So it should be like this:

```
forkJoin(a$, b$, c$).pipe(
  map(x => resultSelector(...x))
)
```